# Generate a list of characters based on pre-defined values

Tags: c++, random

Hoping someone can help me out.
I am trying to create a basic little program that will generate a list of values from a pre-defined list of acceptable characters.

These characters will be - 'H', '/', 'L'.

The program should print these out in a random order with the majority of them being '/' with about 5% being 'L' and 5% being 'H'. (The percentages can vary).
And the program should ask or have a variable that can determine how many characters it will print (i.e. 5 or 5000).

An example of the print out Im looking for:

```
/
/
/
/
/
L
/
/
/
/
/
H
H
/
/
/
/
```

Etc.

What would the best way be around this? Im really stumped and have no idea where to begin.
Obviously I would create a list of the said characters.
But how do I make the program favour one over the other based on percentages?

This is part of work that Im doing at my job where I have to generate a set of dummy data in various stages so this would save me hours of work if I can figure it out.

Any guidance or pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: have you done any code that you could show us? :)

Comment: `how do I make the program favour one over the other based on percentages?` - Choose a random number from 1 to 100. If the number is lower then 5, output 'L'; If the number is greater then 6 and lower then 10, output 'H'; If the number is greater then 11, output '/'.

Comment: Here is a simple algorithm you can start with. Create an array of 100 chars. Fill the array with the valid characters using the percentages you specified ie. 5 - `L`, 5 - `H` and 90 - `/`, now you can randomly index into the array and print the selected character. Since there are more `/`s in the array the chances are higher that you hit those. There are better ways, ie. pick a random number and check the value against a range to get the distribution you require, but start with the array and you will probably evolve other solutions from there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers everyone.

I managed to figure it out based on the comments.

The end code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
ofstream myfile;

void GenerateRandom() {
    int randomNumber;

    for (int index = 0; index < 100; index++) { //Index can be changed to generate more lines if needed
        randomNumber = (rand() % 100) + 1;


        if (randomNumber <= 2) {
            myfile << "H" << endl;
        }
        if (randomNumber > 2 && randomNumber <= 6) {
            myfile << "L" << endl;
        }
        else {
            myfile << "/" << endl;
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    myfile.open("C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Test.txt");
    GenerateRandom();
    myfile.close();
}
```

Thanks for the help again!